# date format getting changed

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy date  in format `"dd-mm-yy"` to a cell .
But while entering at cell it is in `"mm-dd-yy"` format,I believe this happens when date is less than 12

```
Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 40).Value = Format(TextBox3.Value, "dd-mm-yy HH:mm:ss")

Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 40).Value = TextBox3.Value
```

if I enter `03-09-2019` in textbox and press submit .It should be in 03-09-2019 itself.

Instead it is changing to `09-03-2019(09-march-19)`.column format is also in `"dd-mm-yy"` format .it was working fine when date was `"30-08-19"`

Comment: I'd use a Date variable and give the cell the Date variable instead the textbox value.

Comment: there are multiple textboxes .could explain little more on how to use date variable

Comment: `Dim MyDate As Date` and then `MyDate = TextBox3.Value` to finally pass `MyDate` to the cell

Comment: it is having an error when the textbox is blank .so does this mean i need to create if loop for each and every textbox

Comment: `If Not Textbox3.Value = vbNullString Then` and inside the if you can set the Date Variable.

Comment: i tried    ` If TextBox5.Value <> ""  Then`
  
  
  `startdate = TextBox5.Value`
 
   
   `End If` but it in case the textbox is blank it is enter date as 00-01-1900.how to get  cell as blank if textbox is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can give this a try  (had the same issue as yours the way to solve is to save value in `date var`):

```
Sub tryme()

    Dim TextBoxVal As Date

    If Not TextBox3.Value = vbNullString Then
        If IsEmpty(TextBox3.Value) = False Then



TextBoxVal = TextBox3.Value
TextBoxVal = Format(TextBox3.Value, "dd-mm-yy HH:mm:ss")

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 40)
   TextBoxVal = format(Month(.Value) & "/" & Day(.Value) & "/" & Year(.Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")

End With
Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 40).Value = TextBoxVal
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,i tried it but now if textbox is blank ,Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 40) value  is 00-01-00 00:00 is there anyway to make it blank

Comment: @AshwinSooraj add an `Else` to the if statement, and then `Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 40).Value = vbNullstring` inside the `Else`

Comment: sorry my mistake it worked just fine .thanks for the help

Comment: @AshwinSooraj Glad I could help you! May I ask you to accept my answer ?

Comment: @Dorian  still the date is coming in  different format.

Comment: @AshwinSooraj please try my edit, I bet it will solve your issue

Comment: @AshwinSooraj Waiting for your feedbacks ;)

Comment: @Dorian thanks for the edit. I left the office.will try tomorrow and will update you.hope it works. right now for a workaround, I am using `dd-mmm-yy` format.in the edit you entered `" format(Month(.Value) & "/" & Day(.Value) & "/" & Year(.Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")"` may i know why you used month/day/year

Comment: @AshwinSooraj Did this solve your issue ? I founded it because i had the same issue as yours several month ago tell me if your issue is fixed pls

Comment: @Dorian, sorry i couldn't try it.i will be going to office only on next Friday.will try and let you know.mean while can you please explain how the edited code works.

Comment: @AshwinSooraj  If this issue is solved May I ask you to accept this answer ? Click [here to see how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)